# JQuery - Optimize class toggler?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have an element, when clicked, would check the class of a different element.

If it has a specific class, it'll remove it, and replace it with a different class.
Again, if clicked, it'll reverse that process with the swapped class name.

(to give a visual, the class is a lovely Star Icon, and it's shaded version)

I think my code below is a little too verbose.
Can anyone see a better/shorter way to state it?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


   $(".clickme").click(function(){ 

     if($("#staricon").hasClass("starON")){

         $("#staricon").removeClass("starON").addClass("starSHADED"); 

     }else if($("#staricon").hasClass("starSHADED")){

         $("#staricon").removeClass("starSHADED").addClass("starON");   
     }


  });

});
</script>
```

Also, `starON` and `starSHADED` are part of a sprite.
The code above works!  But I'm sure it can be optimized.

I see jQuery has a `.toggleClass()` API, and I'm running into swapping the two classes incorrectly.

Comment: Did you have any errors with `$("#staricon").toggleClass('starON').toggleClass('starSHADED');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#staricon').toggleClass('starSHADED').toggleClass('starON');
```

Comment: this did it!  I did not consider toggleClass for both in the same statement.

Answer (score 2):

First, set your selected element to a variable (always a good rule of thumb for jQuery if you'll be operating on it more than once).

Second, is there a particular reason you need a class for both states? I would give it a shaded star image by default, and override that when it has the starON class. Then a single `toggleClass` can do all the work.

```
$('#staricon').toggleClass("starON");
```

Comment: And, yes, my second piece of advice negates my first in this case. Still think it was worth mentioning, though.